# How can I execute logout() when I kill process?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid app using ionic and Strophe.

I have a problem in my source.

If I kill the app by double pressing home button after login my app. (iphone)

It does not change the user status from online to offline.

I wanna execute logout() when I kill the app. (kill by double pressing iphone home button or task killer in Android)

```
$scope.logOut = function() {
    BOSH.disconnect();
}
```

How can I execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may implement UIApplicationDelegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

it invokes just before the app is killed

Answer (score 1):

you probably export the application to native implementation and 
write an "Application" class(a class that extends Application class and declare the name of the class in Manifest Application tag) for android and implement "onTerminate()" method for logout,

And do implement "- (void)applicationonWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application" for ios in "UIApplicationDelegate".